# How to copy txt/ doc File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dts

I want to copy a txt file from one folder to another. While coping i need to check whether the file exists or not, if yess then replace the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination, True)` to copy a file. The third parameter says to overwrite any existing file).

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) for details.